# Is there a way to make shift+Alt-like reverse?

Tags: keyboard

I have 5 languages on my Windows keyboard, I often switch between them using the Shift+Alt keys. Many times I go to the 2nd language from what I am, by clicking once the mentioned two keys, but when I want to go back to the previous language, I have to click Shift +Alt 4 times more. Is there A way to make shift+Alt-like reverse?
(N.b. My system is Windows 11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I want to go back to the previous language

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to switch between the two recently used languages:

> [image]

Source: [Keyboard shortcuts in Windows - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> (not to be confused with <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> which does nothing) goes through the list backwards. The same is true for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> vs <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>. I can't find this feature documented anywhere, but I have used it on Windows 10 and 7.